# Transform a logistic equation into a linear ODE using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the logistic equation:

$$\frac {dP}{dt} = k(t)P\left(1- \frac{P}C\right)$$

where $k(t)$ represents a growth rate, and $C$ is carrying capacity. How would you use the substitution:

$$u = \frac1P$$

to transform the logistic equation into a linear ODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$
\frac {dP}{dt} = k(t)P\left(1- \frac{P}{C}\right)
$$ one has
$$
\frac{\frac {dP}{dt}}{P^2} = k(t)\left(\frac1P- \frac1{C}\right)
$$ giving with
$$
u=\frac1P,\qquad u'=-\frac{P'}{P^2},
$$ 
$$
-u'=k \left(u-\frac1C\right)
$$ or the linear ODE

> $$
> u'+ku=\frac kC
> $$